# ClearFilter button in Syncfusion appears larger than usual

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion GridDataControl in my application. The application is based on c#, wpf concepts.

I just updated the dll's to the newer versions.

I have FilterBar property set in my control and also showFilterStatusMessage set to true in my control.

However suddenly the 'ClearFilter' button, that appears on the left side of the status bar started showing bigger.

Didn't understand whether it is because i updated the dll's.

Any idea, if how can i customise the things in that status message bar and make that button size reduced.

It will be a great help.

Thanks,
Manali

Answer (score 0):

In the below sample I have edited the control template of GridDataControl. By default the height and width for “PART_CloseButton” is set to 15. So, the Height and Width of the close Button in FilterStatusBar won’t change. To ensure this, copy and paste the GriddataControl style from the attached sample to your application. 
[sampleapplication](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/95320/GDC_TestSample1341797935298.zip)

Please let us know if you have any questions.

Thanks,
Sivakumar